# Incorrect output due to regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I had a pdf in which names are written after a '/'

Eg: /John Adam Will Newman

I want to extract the names starting with '/',

the code which i wrote is :

`names=re.compile(r'((/)((\w)+(\s)))+')`

However, it produces just first name of the string "JOHN" and that too two times not the rest of the name.

Comment: Please provide a more complete code example which would show how you use the regexp. I suspect you use the wrong group number as you specify too many useless groups.

Comment: this is the only code to extract names from the pdf!

Answer (score 0):

Your `+` is at the wrong position; your regexp, as it stands, would demand `/John /Adam /Will /Newman`, with a trailing space.

`r'((/)((\w)+(\s))+)'` is a little better; it will accept `/John Adam Will`, with a trailing space; won't take `Newman`, because there is nothing to match `\s`.

`r'((/)(\w+(\s\w+)*))'` matches what you posted. Note that it is necessary to repeat one of the sequences that match a name, because we want N-1 spaces if there are N words.

(As Ondřej Grover says in comments, you likely have too many unneeded capturing brackets, but I left that alone as it hurts nothing but performance.)

Comment: okay that works, what if  I would want to  print just the entire name on the screen without showing results of all groups ? I tried this,
        namelist=names.findall(text) 

        pyperclip.copy(namelist)
but it gives me error

Answer (score 0):

I think you define way too many unnamed regexp groups. I would do something like this

```
import re
s = '/John Adam Will Newman'
name_regexp = re.compile(r'/(?P<name>(\w+\s*)+)')
match_obj = name_regexp.match(s)  # match object
group_dict = match_obj.groupdict()  # dict mapping {group name: value}
name = group_dict['name']
```

- `(?P<name>...)` starts a named group
- `(\w+\s*)` is a group matching one or more alphanum characters, possibly followed by some whitespace
- the match object returned by the `.match(s)` method has a method `groupdict()` which returns a `dict` which is mapping from group names to their contents

Comment: I didn't exactly understand this part of the code, match(s).groupdict()['name']

Comment: I made it more verbose, hoe this helps.